# MVVM Light Dispatcher helper design time error

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light, dispatcher

During construction of one of the View models for a Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT application, I have a call to `DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI`

I initialize `DispatcherHelper` during runtime at App.xaml.cs OnLauched event handler, but during design time this initialization is not done so when I call `DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI`, I get an Exception with the message "The DispatcherHelper is not initialized"

Is there any way to avoid this issue during design time other than calling `DistpatcherHelper` conditionally, checking `ViewModelBase.IsInDesignMode` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the question, one possible way to avoid this issue is checking whether we are in design mode first as done in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/camilomartinez/1bdb9b6a486fce795dab):

```
using System;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading;

namespace MvvmLight.Helpers
{
    public class DesignAwareDispatcherHelper
    {
        public static void CheckDesignModeInvokeOnUI(Action action)
        {
            if (action == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                action();
            }
            else
            {
                DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(action);
            }
        }
    }
}
```